# How can I select single indices over a dimension in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

Assume I have a tensor `sequences` of shape `[8, 12, 2]`. Now I would like to make a selection of that tensor for each first dimension which results in a tensor of shape `[8, 2]`. The selection over dimension 1 is specified by indices stored in a long tensor `indices` of shape `[8]`.

I tried this, however it selects each index in `indices` for each first dimension in `sequences` instead of only one.

```
sequences[:, indices]
```

How can I make this query without a slow and ugly `for` loop?

Answer (score 9):

```
sequences[torch.arange(sequences.size(0)), indices]
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. Turns out very easy in the end :).

Comment: fantastic, much easier to grok than messing with `gather`

Answer (score 0):

[torch.index_select](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.index_select.html) solves your problem more easily than torch.gather since you don't have to adapt the dimensions of the indeces. Indeces must be a tensor. For your case

```
indeces = [0,2]
a = torch.rand(size=(3,3,3))
torch.index_select(a,dim=1,index=torch.tensor(indeces,dtype=torch.long))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable by `torch.gather`, but you need to convert your index tensor first by

- `unsqueeze` it to match the number of dimension of your input tensor
- `repeat_interleave` it to match the size of last dimension

Here is an example based on your description:

```
# original indices dimension [8]
# after first unsueeze, dimension is [8, 1]
indices = torch.unsqueeze(indices, 1)

# after second unsueeze, dimension is [8, 1, 1]
indices = torch.unsqueeze(indices, 2)

# after repeat, dimension is [8, 1, 2]
indices = torch.repeat_interleave(indices, 2, dim=2)

# now you have the right dimension for torch.gather
# don't forget to squeeze the redundant dimension
# result has dimension [8, 2] 
result = torch.gather(sequences, 1, indices).squeeze()
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using [torch.Tensor.gather](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.gather.html)

```py
sequences = torch.randn(8,12,2)
# defining the indices as a 1D Tensor of random integers and reshaping it to use with Tensor.gather
indices = torch.randint(sequences.size(1),(sequences.size(0),)).unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(-1).repeat(1,1,sequences.size(-1))
# indices shape: (8, 1, 2)
output = sequences.gather(1,indices).squeeze(1)
# output shape: (8, 2)
```